# How to modify a manifest file when using Ansible to install a service on a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-helm, high-availability

I am trying to automate making a HA cluster with Ansible.

Normally I have two options to install the load balancer (MetalLb), with manifest or helm.

I really like that `helm` has a `--values` option. This is useful because I can add toleration to the MetalLB speakers, that way I can deploy them in the nodes that I dont want to deploy jobs on.

When making the playbook I want to have a way to deploy the MetalLB speakers with the toleration so they can get deploy but I don't want to install helm on one of the nodes.

When the playbook is ran I can download the manifest file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.7/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml but now I want to be able to add the tolerations. How can I accomplish this without me downloading the yaml file and editing it myself, something like the `--values` option in helm would be nice

Comment: As far as I know, [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) is the "kubectl version of helm"; have you already tried that?

Comment: Looks like Ansible supports Jinja2 templating: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#template-module

Comment: @mdaniel I read something related to kustomize this week but I couldn't get it to work. I also saw that there is a kubectl patch but I don't know what is the best way to do in this case.

Comment: I think you have two viable solutions here: use Kustomize, for which there is [support in Anisble](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/kustomize_lookup.html), or use Ansible's native templating mechanism, which provides you with a feature set that is almost identical to what you get using Helm templates.

Comment: @Fcmam5 I didn't see any parameter that allows me to modify the file so I can add the toleration

Comment: @larsks I will check that. I need first update the tittle to make it more specific to ansible since I am getting down voting...

Comment: My advice is that you close this question, look into the suggestions that have been provided, and come back when you have tried implementing a solution and have a specific technical question. You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/ lays out the general idea of how kustomize is going to work: take some bases, apply some transformations to them. In most cases, the [strategic merge](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/#patch-using-inline-strategic-merge) behaves like folks expect, and is how the `kubectl patch` you mentioned behaves<sup>1</sup>. But, dealing with array values in merges is tricky, so I have had better luck with using [JSON Patch array add support](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A.16), which is what we will use here

```yaml
# the contents of "kustomization.yaml" in the current directory
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.7/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml
patches:
  - target:
      version: v1
      group: apps
      kind: DaemonSet
      namespace: metallb-system
      name: speaker
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/template/spec/tolerations/-
        value: {"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"example.com/some-taint","operator":"Exists"}
```

Then, using [`kubectl kustomize .`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kubectl/kustomize/) we see the result from applying that patch:

```yaml
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        operator: Exists
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
        operator: Exists
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: example.com/some-taint
        operator: Exists
```

Obviously if you wanted to wholesale replace the tolerations, you may have better luck with the strategic merge flavor, but given that your question didn't specify and this case is the harder of the two, I started with it

---

FN 1: I saw you mention `kubectl patch` but that is for editing **existing** kubernetes resources, so after you already deployed your metallb-native.yaml into the cluster, only then would `kubectl patch` do anything for you. Using `kustomize` is the helm-replacement in that it is designed for the manifests to go into the cluster in the right state, versus fixing it up later